# Need some train sounds ASAP

Tags: design, recording, samples

Hi guys,

I need a few different train sounds ASAP for an advertising animation I'm working on.

I'm looking for some onboard (but outside of the train) sound (so we can hear the train moving along as if we are on it but outside) and also some pass-bys. They need to be as 'clean' and 'upfront' as possible' very little distance and background ambience.

Anyone know where I can get some good samples like this? Particularly if anyone knows of some good libraries that contain a wide variety of real world sounds.

thanks in advance for any help,

Simon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

www.soundsnap.com or www.sounddogs.com for grabbing single effects

The Sound Collectors club (http://thesoundcollectorsclub.wordpress.com/) just did a trains theme last month but you can not get access unless you contribute a original recording yourself.  Some good stuff available though if you want to contribute to the collection.

SoundIdeas series 6000 disc 6033 is full of train sounds.

Rabbit Ears Audio has a library called Metal Machines that would be a great sweetener library full of old giant metal clacks and bangs.  http://rabbitearsaudio.com/rea004-metal-machines/

If it is an old steam train then JordenFehrFX has a library called power from the past.  http://jordanfehrfx.posterous.com/35425043

Your best bet might be The recordist train SFX.  I don't have these libraries but Mr Bry's work has a history of being top notch.  http://www.therecordist.com/soundbox-sfx/soundbox-sd/trains

Comment: Oh Crap, yes Paul at Airbourne Sound can set you up too.  

Comment: You can audition short samples of what's in the current collection of train sounds at The Sound Collectors' Club by visiting http://thesoundcollectorsclub.wordpress.com/browse-the-collection/trains-design/

Answer (score 1):

Hi Simon,

In order to add to the really good suggestions above, I have just released my first two sound effects collections.  Have a look at the train sound collection [here](http://www.martinpinsonnault.com/sound-effects-collections/mpsfx_trains01/). You can find a few onbard exterior rides and a lot more!

Cheers to all SSD members and sound designers on the web!

Martin

[www.martinpinsonnault.com](http://www.martinpinsonnault.com/)

Comment: @Martin thanks for this post. I did not know about your SFX libraries. Looks like useful stuff. 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [freesound.org](http://freesound.org)?

Comment: be careful with freesounds.org as the user agreement makes it hard to use their sounds on any commercial production.  

Comment: Fair point.  The last time I used a train sound, I played the drums (hat-hat-kick-kick..sn-sn-hat-hat-kick-kick..) and slowed the tape down.  Probably easier to just go with the other suggestions.  Ha!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simon,

That sounds like a cool project.

I have some at [Airborne Sound](http://www.airbornesound.com/vehicle/train.html). A mix of diesel, passenger, steam, freight, etc. They're all clean and upfront.

Direct links:

- [general trains passing](http://www.airbornesound.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=train%20passing), a variety of rail clatter passes and rail scrapes
- [Some loopable train passing
  elements](http://www.airbornesound.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=train%20loop)
- I have [steam train exterior
  onboards](http://www.airbornesound.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=train%20onboard), but no diesel onboards

I also have a "Jet Set" collection pack of a few various [train sounds here](http://www.airbornesound.com/vehicle/train/jet-set-sound-pack-06-trains-sound-effects.html) at a discounted price.

I was particularly happy with the exterior passes. I felt they have lots of power and energy and character. All recorded with the Neumann 191 mic.

All sounds have Soundminer metadata, by the way.

Good luck with the project.

-Paul

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this?

http://thesoundcollectorsclub.wordpress.com/browse-the-collection/trains-design/

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simon,
If you search for > train close < at    www.your-sounds.com    you`ll find 300 hits.
Professionally recorded, soundminer ready. Please check our Prepaid Accounts to find interesting offers.

Eckhard Kuchenbecker

http://your-sounds.com

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simon,

In addition to all of the other excellent resources mentioned here, I'm going to be recording those exact type of sounds on the 26th of this month.  That may be outside of your timeframe, but if this is an ongoing project I'd suggest you back my [kickstarter project](http://kck.st/m0A9rT) to gain access to the recordings, since I won't be selling them later.

Comment: I am already a backer on this kickstarter project, everyone should get on board as it is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Simon,

As mentioned I do have trains. Exterior but no onboard. They were recorded some time ago. 16-Bit 44.1K.

http://www.therecordist.com/soundbox-sfx/soundbox-sd/trains

Pauls train sounds are really good and he travels the world way more than I do :)

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: Thanks, Frank! :)
  
Simon, like others on this page I also highly recommend Frank's libraries - his effects are well know industry-wide for their quality and clarity.  
  
Frank, any plans to publish those trains you recorded in North Idaho that you wrote about on your blog a few months ago? Quite enjoyed those.
  
http://www.therecordist.com/train-recording-3-13-2011
